# What is the big Oh notation for the following series.

Tags: limits, asymptotics

I have the series $1+3+9+27+... + 3^n$ . I need to find the Big O solution.

What I have tried.

The above series is a Geometric Progression with r=3. SO the sum would be.

$ [1* 3^{n+1} - 1]/2 $

How do I get the Big Oh notation of the above expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the most significant term, which is $3^{n+1}/2$.  That turns out to be $3/2 \cdot 3^n$, so the expression is $O(3^n)$.